# C# do i need to dispose mail that is sent async?

Tags: c#, smtp, dispose

Using a button to sent mail async and disposing of it in the task itself. Is this the correct way to do it?

Or do I need a `catch` inside the task and do I need a `finally` dispose on the button click?

And do I need to dispose of other things like the smtpclient? The mails don't have any attachments they are all just plain text.

```cs
private async void closeorder.Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await SendEmail();
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("mail has not been sent");
    }
}
```

```cs
private async Task SendEmail()
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(emailfile)
    {
        String[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(emailfile);
        foreach (string line in Lines)
            message.To.Add(line);
    }
    else
    {  
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(emailfile,"");
        TextWriter Email = new StreamWriter(emailfile, true);
        Email.Writeline("foo@email.com");
        Email.close();
    }

    try
    {
        MailAdress fromAddress = new MailAddress("goo@email.com","order");
        smtpClient.Host "";
        smtpClient.Port xx;
        smtpClient.credentials = ("""");
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "";
        message.IsBodyHtml = True;
        message.Body = Mybody();
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
    finally 
    {
        message.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Sorry if formatting isn't the best typed on mobile.

Comment: `TextWriter Email` also needs a `using`

Comment: The ```Email.close``` does the same thing right?

Comment: No it won't close it in the event of an exception. A `using` is effectively a `try` `finally` with the `Dispose` call in the `finally`

Comment: Alright ill change it. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` implement the `IDisposable` interface so you should dispose them.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=net-6.0

The fact it is in a asynchronous flow does not invalidate the fact you need to dispose properly those objects.

But you can avoid to use the try/catch/finally with the `using` keyword:

```
using(var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
using(var message = new MailMessage()) 
{
  // Your code
}
```

It will generate for you (behing the scene) the try/catch/finally blocks and the call to `dispose`.

Comment: I am using c# 7.3 with .Net 4.7.2 which i think doesn't have support for the using method. Is my code fine then other then adding the smtpClient dispose?

Comment: Using statement (do not confond with using directive used to import namespace) is  existing since a really long time so C# 7.3 is not an issue here :-) Except the missing dispose/using I don't see other issue.

Comment: No clue then, it gave me errors i had to use lang version 8.0. I am going to add the dispose. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Duivelbryan Were you perhaps using the `using var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();` syntax, which IS from a later language version?

Comment: @MatthewWatson no but i just figured out my mistake i changed my ```SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();```  to the provided using code. While i had to change the try into the using code. However now i am getting a different error "a local parameter named smtpClient & message cannot be declared in this scope.... This is a formatting issue right?

Comment: And that fixed was an even bigger mistake. I figured it out now i hope lol. Changed my ```SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();     MailMessage message = new MailMessage();``` to the provided using code AND remove the try finally etc.. completely and ofcourse place the correct ```{}```  this seems to work now. But i got another question how can i check if it is actually disposed off?

Comment: If you use `using` you know it will be disposed, so you don't need to check.